# How do I use "hypnotic fascination" in a sentence?

Tags: phrases

Aren't "hypnotic" and "fascination" two words?

Comment: They are two words, yes - I'm not sure what your point is, given that obviously sentences contain more than one word. "Hypnotic fascination" seems to be a term used by some hypnotists.

Comment: _Checking the ELU review queues has a kind of hypnotic fascination for some._

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hypnotic fascination is a noun phrase. For more examples: https://grammar.yourdictionary.com/parts-of-speech/nouns/noun-phrases.html